# subsets of groups which have to be closed no matter what

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

One example of a subset of a group $G$ which has to be closed in any topology on $G$ compatible with the group operations is a centraliser. Are there any other interesting examples?

Comment: What is "topology compatible with the group operations" and why does the centralizer have to be closed? E.g., is the anti-discrete topology compatible?

Comment: First: this only holds if the group is Hausdorff. Second: any set which is described by quant or-free equations in the language of groups. Third: is this a research-related question?

Comment: @Alex: compatible means that the group is a topological group, i.e., the group operations are continuous.

Comment: @anton, but all topologies are Hausdorff.

Comment: @jmc: that's exactly my point: definitions should be agreed upon :) But, **assuming** Hausdorff, any finite subset is closed. OP should be more specific about what kind of subsets is of interest.

Comment: @jmc: no they are not.

Comment: @anton, just kidding. Why would the word exist after all. I was trying to point out a common mistake, like Alex also points out.

Comment: Voting to reopen in light of Anton's nice answer.

Comment: Anton, yes, this is related to a research problem I am working on about the rigidity of the group topology on certain locally compact groups, and yes, you are right that I should have said Hausdorff.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Subsets of a group that are closed with respect to any Hausdorff group topology
are called *unconditionally closed*.

Clearly, all *algebraic* sets are unconditionally closed, where a subset of a group $G$ is called *algebraic* if it is an intersection of finite unions of the sets of solutions to some equations with coefficient from $G$.

[A.A.Markov proved](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=6243&option_lang=eng) that for countable groups the converse is also true:
$$
\hbox{unconditionally closed = algebraic}.
$$
For uncountable groups, this is not always the case as follows from works of S. Shelah (under CH) and G. Hesse.

Comment: Klyachkon: Is there any English text about the work of Markov? Is there similar works for other algebraic systems?

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer, rather a longer (and not very deep) remark about the question of the topology and the assumption that it should be Hausdorff.

Not every topology that makes a group a topological group is Hausdorff. But to any topological group we can associate a Hausdorff topological group in a canonical way. Let $G$ be a topological group and denote by $H$ the closure of $\{e\}$. Then $H$ is a normal subgroup in $G$, and the quotient group $G/H$ is Hausdorff with respect to the quotient topology. See Proposition 1-4 (vi) on page 6 of Ramakrishnan and Valenza, Fourier analysis on number field, 1999.

Based on this result, Ramakrishnan and Valenza write "Part (vi) shows that every topological group projects by a continuous homomorphism onto a topological group with Hausdorff topology. In this sense the assumption that a given group is Hausdorff is not too serious."

Nonetheless, the assumption plays an important role in Rupert's question. For, if we take the trivial topology $\mathcal{O}=\{\emptyset,G\}$, the $H=G$ and $G/H$ is the trivial group. Btw, the example of the trivial topology shows that the answer to the question (if we don't require Hausdorff) is easy: $G$ and the empty set are the only subsets that are closed in any topology on $G$ that makes $G$ a topological group.